# Copy Data from Word to Excel based on Headings and surrounding text

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am given a Word file which contains 30 cases every week. I have to get data and place them in columns in an Excel file.

The Word file looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3HI9.jpg

I am thinking of two approaches:

1. Add tags on the titles and citations since they don't have headings or anything else that could distinguish them: **/title A vs. B** and **/cite 123 A.B.C. 234** (yellow and purple highlight in the pic).
   Take the paragraph after the /title and /cite.
2. Look for the whole paragraph after "**OVERVIEW:**" since this data is distinguished by this string.

Summary:
I want to copy all case titles (yellow) into a column in an existing Excel sheet, copy all the citations (purple) into another column, copy all overviews (red) into another column, etc.

Sample Excel and Word file used: [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WcZoxLjtXsTiRYTVEvRhEK9Z7avGTbbY)

Note: case names and arrangement in the file attached above will not match since I have already edited and sorted the Excel file. I just need the macro to copy the data and then I would sort it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that you need to get everything into Excel, as such.

```
Sub Sentence_Click()

Dim num As Variant
'Microsoft Word object
Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
'Word document object
Dim WordNam As String
WordNam = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\September Week 1 2017.docx"

'Open word document
objWord.Documents.Open WordNam
j = 1
n = objWord.Documents(WordNam).Paragraphs.Count
For Each num In Array(7, 13, 23)
For i = 1 To n
    If i = num Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(j, 1) = objWord.Documents(WordNam).Paragraphs(i)
        Debug.Print num
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
Next num
'Close objects
objWord.Documents.Close
objWord.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges


End Sub
```

Then parse out the data in Excel, any way you choose.

As you can see, I am importing based on paragraph number, and not based on color.  I think you added those colors; I don't think the document comes to you like that.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. Yes i added the colors to point out the items that are relevant. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write the code for you, but to get you started this code, if pasted into a vb module in Word, will copy any selected text in the current word document into a blank spreadsheet in excel.

```
Sub copytext2XL()
Dim r As Range 'nb this is a Word range, not an Excel range
Dim xl
Dim wb, ws, xlr
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
Set wb = xl.workbooks.Add
Set ws = wb.worksheets(1)
Set xlr = ws.Range("a1")

Set r = Selection.Range
 r.Copy
 xlr.PasteSpecial 3

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try it out.